# Microphone being recognised as a Headphone

Tags: windows, audio, microphone, headphones

I have tried attaching this microphone (3.5mm audio jack) to my android to see if the device was the issue, but it still is not detected. On windows, it comes up as a headphone rather than a microphone, is there anyway to fix this?

This is the microphone I have: https://www.kmart.com.au/product/gaming-microphone-42959564/

Comment: A microphone and headphone are basically the same and can be used the same, it is therefor the port that determines what it is. If you have a standard 3.5mm input, make sure you plug it in on the microphone port, not the speaker/headphones port. Some motherboards can change the port if they detect a different device, in that case, use the control panel to change it back.

Comment: Head*phone* or head*set*?

Comment: @LPChip The one on my laptop is for headphones and audio as it has the headset symbol on it and it has worked previously as a microphone using that jack.

Comment: @u1686_grawity It is recognised as a headphone under the playback setting, though something I have noticed it is recognised as the same device as my headphones which I connect through the same jack.

Comment: Also, the microphone was actually once listed under microphone the first time i plugged it in, it no longer shows up there.

Comment: @LPChip - Also, "a mic & headphone are basically the same" is fine in principal, but wildly misleading in practise.

Comment: @Tetsujin You can use those small earbuds, plug them in a microphone port, shout in it, and it will record. Yes, there are differences, true, but in essence the technology behind it is reversable. Also, you can plug a microphone in a headphone socket, and play music, and it will come out of the microphone.

Comment: @LPChip - yes, I'm fully aware of that, I'm actually a retired sound engineer;) It's still highly misleading in this context. A computer will use a simple 'which pins are connected, at what impedances' to try figure this out. Speakers/headphones will have an impedance between 4 - 250Ω, a cheap mic somewhere in the thousands, 2.000Ω or more …but how does it figure it out if there are 'too many pins' for a mic, but 'too much impedance' for headphones? That's where some struggle.

Comment: Are you saying that microphone doesn't work on you Android phone either? Your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jack [TRS] on your mic is one normally used used for camera mic inputs, rarely for computer mics.

[image] [image]

To a computer, that looks like a headphone jack [TRS], not a headset jack [TRRS], which would look like this

[image]

To a computer, a simple mic jack [TS] should look like this

[image]

Some computers can automatically figure out all the combinations, but few are ever smart enough to be able to tell the difference between headphones & mic if they're both on the same jack type.

A computer will use a simple 'which pins are connected, at what impedances' to try figure this out. Speakers/headphones will have an impedance between 4 - 250Ω, a cheap mic somewhere in the thousands, 2.000Ω or more …but how does it figure it out if there are 'too many pins' for a mic, but 'too much impedance' for headphones? That's where some struggle.

See [CableChick - Understanding TRRS and Audio Jacks](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/) for a more comprehensive guide.

What you need is a camera mic to headset adapter, such as [this one from Røde](https://rode.com/en/accessories/adaptors-cables/sc4) [who make a lot of mics, for cameras & otherwise].

[image]

This will then force your computer to see it as a headset… just without earphones. It may show a phantom output, but you can ignore it.

There used to be additional confusion over the precise pinout of a TRRS jack, but thankfully just about everything has now settled on the CTIA standard.