# Right side of earphone not working when using Splitter?

Tags: audio, microphone, connector, splitter, headphone-jack

I'm using earphones which has mic and left/right dual audio support, and it works fine on pc when plugged in direct port (I'm able to hear both left and right audio clearly) so if I want to use microphone it has a separate mic port.
When I try to use the below splitter to use mic and audio using earphone, and try to balance it, first changed right side seems like the right side is not working or it is very feeble, but when I try to change left side, only then I came to know the right side is very feeble.
Without splitter it works fine, but facing issue when using splitter as during gaming I need to use both audio and mic for gaming and streaming as well.

Mono audio is also off and left and right are equally balanced.

Below is the link for splitter just in case:
https://www.amazon.in/Sounce-Plated-Headphone-Earphone-Splitter/dp/B08BCKN299/ref=sr_1_2?crid=3BX0FE7UHS6UM&keywords=splitter+amazon+2+male+to+1+female&qid=1704874825&sprefix=splitter+amazon+2+male+to+1+femal%2Caps%2C193&sr=8-2

[by the way it is 2 male to 1 female 3.5mm jack connector for splitter]

Any suggestion or idea on how to fix this, I'm using windows 11 on pc ?

Comment: Start here - [CableChick - Understanding TRRS and Audio Jacks](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/) - you need to understand how & why you have the wrong splitter'.

Comment: No, it's not the wrong splitter, I double check the strips and also checked the reviews before buying and seems good to me. 
I also checked the link which you shared, seems the right splitter, it supports stereo audio + have left/right which are indicated. 
It would me more helpful if you can tell how the splitter is wrong, I'm using the one which I have shared the link in ques

Comment: You haven't given us enough clear information. We need to know the pinout of your 1) headset, 2) mic & 3)computer. A head**set** with stereo phones & a mic, uses a TRRS jack, head**phones**, without a mic, has TRS. A simple mic should have TS, [or sometimes TRS which is mainly for cameras, not computers.] The splitter [presumably, their diagrams are a complete fabrication, false imagery] takes TRRS to two separate TRS jacks, with the middle ring of the mic either shorted to tip or disconnected. See also https://superuser.com/questions/1819897/microphone-being-recognised-as-a-headphone